# How to send user to a search page using FAB in Kotlin, for Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, floating-action-button

can anyone help me with this code?

```
p0.btnPlay.setOnClickListener {

    val songName = song.songName
    val songArtist = song.songArtist

    Toast.makeText(mCtx, "You clicked this button!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    val webIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH, Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=$songArtist+$songName"))
    startActivity(webIntent)
}
```

> I am getting an error at `startActivity(webIntent)` : Type mismatch:
>   inferred type is Intent but Context was expected

How do I send a user to a youtube page like this? The toast message works fine, so the button click is connected to the XML.

Comment: Try using `mCtx.startActivity(webIntent)`

Comment: Can you post the complete error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `mCtx` is Activity `context`, then use

```
try {
    val webIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=$songArtist+$songName"))
    mCtx.startActivity(webIntent)
} catch(ex: Exception) {
    ex.stackTrace
}
```

If you are inside fragment then try using

```
try {
    val webIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=$songArtist+$songName"))
    activity!!.startActivity(webIntent)
} catch(ex: Exception) {
    ex.stackTrace
}
```

Comment: Used the first one and the error is gone, but the button doesn't react to it at all. Still displays the toast message though.

Comment: Try using `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` instead of `Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH`

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=$songArtist+$songName");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

startActivity(intent);
```